# vim: how to move window neither use ctrl+w+ nor change default key setting

Tags: vim, split, move

I use split command to open more than one window in the browser,and I want to change the position by using 'ctrl+w+ direction', it will close the current browser tab because of the default key shortcut in Chrome.
I don't want to change any setting in vim or browser, would you help me?
Maybe there are some command like 'next' ?

Comment: Using browser to open fort website and connect to the remote linux machine, and use vim editing more than one file in remote console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`:wincmd`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd) to access any windows commands without having to use the `CTRL-W` keystroke.

For example, `:wincmd H` to make the current window a vertical split taking the whole left side (same as `CTRL-W H` would do.)

---

But at some point you might end up wanting to set a mapping. Do you want to type `:wincmd w` every time you want to switch to the next window? Even if you don't want to set that up in vimrc, perhaps a quick `:map \w <c-w>` is all you need to use `\w` instead of `CTRL-W` everywhere? Or pick something similarly short. You can type this mapping about as quickly as a `:wincmd` command and then you can have all window commands accessible without having to hit the problematic `CTRL-W`...

Comment: THX, good, :wincmd can solve my problem, this way just for temporary.

Comment: Or `noremap \\ <C-w>`